# Importing variable directly yields a different value than importing its module in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have three modules:

- `constants`, which contains loaded configuration and other stuff in a class
- `main`, which initializes `constants` when it is run
- `user`, which imports `constants` and accesses its configuration.

`constants` module (simplified) looks like this:

```
class Constants:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        # Read values from INI file
        config = self.read_inifile(filename)
        self.somevalue = config['ex']['ex']

    def read_inifile(self, filename):
        # reads inifile

constants: Constants = None

def populate_constants(filename):
    global constants
    constants = Constants(filename)
```

A simple object which should hold the configuration, nothing groundbreaking.

The function `populate_constants()` is called from `main` on program startup.

Now the weirdness happens - when I import the `constants` module from `user` like this, the `constants` is `None`:

```
from toplevelpkg.constants import constants
print(constants)

None
```

However, if I import it like this, `constants` is initialized as one would expect:

```
from toplevelpkg import constants
print(constants.constants)

<trumpet.constants.Constants object at 0x035AA130>
```

Why is that?

EDIT: in my code, the function attempting to read `constants` is run asynchronously via `await loop.run_in_executor(None, method_needing_import)`. Not sure if this may cause issues?

*(and as a side-question, is it a good practice to have a configuration-holding object which parses the config file and provides it as its member variables?)*

Comment: is `constants: Constants = None` exactly what your code has? That does not look like correct syntax to me.

Comment: Also, are you importing after calling `populate_constants`?

Comment: 1) it is a correct syntax as of Python 3.6 (variable type annotations)

Comment: 2) Yes, the import happens after calling the functions. I have added some printing statements to check what `constants` is and there does seem to be what I expect except for the case written above.

Comment: Sounds like you just found the problem.

Comment: Not sure I follow?

Comment: I'm really trying to understand how you've structured your code though. You say that the `populate_constants` is called in main, but the import for `constants` happens in the user module.

Comment: what other calls are asynchronous? If you have multiple async calls then you can't guarantee that one will happen before the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's indeed a difference between

```
from mymodule import obj
(...)
do_something_with(obj)
```

and

```
import mymodule
(...)
do_something_with(mymodule.obj)
```

In the first case, it acts as :

```
 import mymodule
 obj = mymodule.obj
 del mymodule
```

which means that at this point, in the current module, `obj` is a "global" (which in python actually means 'module-level', not 'application-wide') name bound to whatever `mymodule.obj` was *when it was imported* (in your case : `None`). From then on, `mymodule.obj` and the module-local `obj` names live in different namespaces (the first one in `mymodule` namespace, the second one in the current module namespace), and rebinding `mymodule.obj` from anywhere won't change anything to what the current module's `obj` is bound to. Actually, it's exactly as if you were doing this:

```
a = 2
b = a
a = 4
```

After the third statement, `b` is obviously still bound to `2` - rebinding `a` to `4` doesn't impact `b`.

In the second case (`import mymodule`) what get's bound in the importing module's namespace is the whole `mymodule` object, so if `mymodule.obj` gets rebound (from within `mymodule` or anywhere else) the change will be visible in the importing module. In this case it's equivalent to

```
a = {"x": 2}
b = a
a["x"] = 4
```

In which case the change will be visible from `b["x"]` as well since `a` and `b` are still bound to the very same object.

wrt/ your side question: yes, having some "config" object is quite a common pattern. You just may want to make sure you can build it "from scratch" too (I mean, not necessarily from a config file) to make unittesting easier.