# python - best method of changing variable values in diferrent modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I have four variables that are required to be changed in specific modules and read in specific modules. To clarify, these modules are 'health', 'max_health, 'attack' and 'gold'.

The gold is meant to increase whenever an enemy is defeated in each of the application's three levels and reduced when a piece of armor/a weapon is bought in the armory module, the health is meant to reduce when attacked by an enemy and restored in the hospital module, the max_health is dependent on which armor has been equipped in the armory module and the same applies to the attack and which weapon has been equipped.

The problem is that the set values are always taken from a module where I have stored each of the variables along with the functions of the applications.

Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way of initially taking the value from each of the variables when the application first launches and then as the application goes on, the values can be changed and read in the modules as described above.

Any feedback would be widely appreciated.

EDIT:
The variables are globalised and established in StoreData as follows:

```
global max_health
global health
global attack
global gold

max_health = 100
health = 100
attack = 5
gold = 0
```

These variables are then imported into each module as follows:

```
from PKG.StoreData import hub_from_level1_travel, max_health, attack, gold, health

from PKG.StoreData import health, max_health, attack, gold, hub_from_level2_travel

from PKG.StoreData import health, max_health, attack, gold, hub_from_level3_travel

from PKG.StoreData import hospital_heal, hub_from_hospital_travel, max_health, health, gold, attack

from PKG.StoreData import hospital_travel, armoury_travel, level1_start, level2_start, level3_start, exit, health, max_health, attack, gold

from PKG.StoreData import hub_from_armoury_travel, max_health, health, gold, attack
```

The values for the variables are changed as initially described but the changes do not replace the set values shown in StoreData. Instead, the values are taken from StoreData when any module that isn't StoreData is in use and takes the initially set values instead. I can't wrap my head around any potential fixes for this issue so feedback would be eternally grateful at this moment.

Comment: You may want to use the [Flyweight Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html)

Comment: This sounds pretty straightforward. What exactly isn't working? You need to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem is that once a variable is changed in one module, it instantly resets to it's set value when the module changes. Importing and globalising the variables does no good.

Comment: When the module changes? What do you mean? Please give an mcve...

Comment: I think you really want to learn about OO and avoid mutable globals. Well if  you fancy your mental health that is...

Comment: When I wish to change the active module, a function is used to import the desired module and make that the active module. I would provide an example but this is for a project and I would prefer it if the example does not fall into the act of plagiarism.

Comment: FWIW, your explanations are rather unclear but your problem might be similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780544/importing-variable-directly-yields-a-different-value-than-importing-its-module-i/

Comment: What does "the active module" means ??? And you don't have to post you actual code, just the minimal similar code exposing the problem.

Comment: I'm only a beginner so I'll explain the best way I can. The four variables are in a module called StoreData, which does as the name says. The values from these variables are used in all of the modules mentioned in the original question. However, when these values change in a module that isn't StoreData, the changes are not saved across the rest of the modules. Instead, the variables only use the set values were set in StoreData. I'll provide an edit to the question which elaborates the issue with code.

Comment: Edit has been posted.

Comment: Your `global` statements are totally useless, the variables are already in global scope...

Comment: So, when you modify a variable, *it doesn't change the source code*. You need to wrap your head around the distinction between source code and the actual program running in memory. You are likely looking for *data persistence*. So the most naive way would be to store your data as a file that you edit when you want to permanently change it, then reload it every time you run your program.

Comment: Could you provide an example so I am able to learn what to do for next time?